# IOS Multipeer Connectivity - Only sending part of my object

Tags: swift, multipeer-connectivity

I've created an object with several properties to send: 1 string (sessiondate), an array of another object, 1 time interval and 1 Int (sessiondistance). I send this object using multipleer connectivity, and the devices register that they are receiving data. However, the integer isn't received. It becomes nil on receiving devices.

Thanks for any help!

[This is the relevant code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51vPm.png)

func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
        switch state {
        case MCSessionState.connected:
            print("Connected: (peerID.displayName)")

```
        joinedSession = true
        let hosting = ViewController().hostCheck()
        print("InMCSessionConnected")
        if(hosting == false){

        }
        if(hosting == true){


            if(self.ConnectedUsers.text?.range(of: peerID.displayName) == nil){
                DispatchQueue.main.async  {
                self.ConnectedUsers.text?.append(peerID.displayName + ", ")
                }
            }

            HostingSession.noJoined = HostingSession.noJoined + 1;
            print(HostingSession.noJoined)

            print(SessionsManager.SessionInception.last?.SessionDistance)
            print(SessionsManager.SessionInception.last?.SessionDate)
            print("SendingData")
            sendData(SessionsManager.SessionInception.last!)
            print("SendingData")

        }


    case MCSessionState.connecting:
        print("Connecting: \(peerID.displayName)")

    case MCSessionState.notConnected:
        print("Not Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
        joinedSession = false

    }
}
func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    //This is called when data arrives
    print("Starting Received Data")

    let hosting = ViewController().hostCheck()
    if(hosting == false){

    let SessionSent = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! Sessions)
    print(SessionSent.SessionDistance)

    SessionsManager.SessionInception.append(SessionSent)//appends the session sent
    //2 method gets the current date and line below appends this date to title
    let currentSession = SessionsManager.SessionInception.last
    let currentSessionDate = (currentSession?.SessionDate)!
    print(currentSessionDate)
    reloadView()

    //Creates the table
    TableView.rowHeight = 90
    TableView.delegate = self
    TableView.dataSource = self
    TableView.reloadData()

    print("Finished Received Data")
        //ReadyButton.enabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I got this working by sending each part of the object individually. See below:

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
    switch state {
    case MCSessionState.connected:
        print("Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")

        joinedSession = true
        let hosting = ViewController().hostCheck()
        print("InMCSessionConnected")
        if(hosting == false){

        }
        if(hosting == true){


            if(self.ConnectedUsers.text?.range(of: peerID.displayName) == nil){
                DispatchQueue.main.async  {
                self.ConnectedUsers.text?.append(peerID.displayName + ", ")
                }
            }

            HostingSession.noJoined = HostingSession.noJoined + 1;
            print(HostingSession.noJoined)

            print(SessionsManager.SessionArray.last?.SessionDistance)
            print(SessionsManager.SessionArray.last?.SessionDate)
            print("SendingData")
            sendData(SessionsManager.SessionArray.last!)
            print("SendingData")
            //MARK: Work around
           sendDistance(SessionsManager.SessionArray.last!.SessionDistance!)
            sendStartTime((SessionsManager.SessionArray.last?.startTime)!)
        }


    case MCSessionState.connecting:
        print("Connecting: \(peerID.displayName)")

    case MCSessionState.notConnected:
        print("Not Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
        joinedSession = false

    }
}
func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    //This is called when data arrives
    print("Starting Received Data")
    let hosting = ViewController().hostCheck()
    if(hosting == false){

    if let SessionSent = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? Sessions)  {


    SessionsManager.SessionArray.append(SessionSent)//appends the session sent
    //2 method gets the current date and line below appends this date to title
    let currentSession = SessionsManager.SessionArray.last
    let currentSessionDate = (currentSession?.SessionDate)!
    print(currentSessionDate)
    reloadView()

    //Creates the table
    TableView.rowHeight = 90
    TableView.delegate = self
    TableView.dataSource = self
    TableView.reloadData()
        }//MARK: Work around
        else if let distanceSent = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? Int) {
        if (distanceSent < 100000){
        SessionsManager.SessionArray.last?.SessionDistance = distanceSent
        print(SessionsManager.SessionArray.last?.SessionDistance)


        }else{
        SessionsManager.SessionArray.last?.startTime = TimeInterval(distanceSent)
        print(SessionsManager.SessionArray.last?.startTime)
        }
        }
    print("Finished Received Data")
        //ReadyButton.enabled = true
    }
}
```

These are the sending subroutines:

```
//MARK: Work around
func sendDistance(_ TheData: Int){
    let dataToSend = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: TheData)

    if mcSession.connectedPeers.count > 0 {//makes sure it is actually sending it to any peers before it attempts
        do {
            try mcSession.send(dataToSend, toPeers: mcSession.connectedPeers, with: .reliable)//Ensures delivery using reliable method, sends dataToSend to all peers connected on mcSession.connectedPeers

        } catch let error as NSError {//Shows an error message if there is a problem
            print(error)
        }



    }

}

func sendStartTime(_ TheData: TimeInterval){
    let dataToSend = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: TheData)

    if mcSession.connectedPeers.count > 0 {//makes sure it is actually sending it to any peers before it attempts
        do {
            try mcSession.send(dataToSend, toPeers: mcSession.connectedPeers, with: .reliable)//Ensures delivery using reliable method, sends dataToSend to all peers connected on mcSession.connectedPeers

        } catch let error as NSError {//Shows an error message if there is a problem
            print(error)
        }



    }



    }

func sendData(_ TheData: NSObject){
    let dataToSend = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: TheData)
    if mcSession.connectedPeers.count > 0 {//makes sure it is actually sending it to any peers before it attempts
            do {
                try mcSession.send(dataToSend, toPeers: mcSession.connectedPeers, with: .reliable)//Ensures delivery using reliable method, sends dataToSend to all peers connected on mcSession.connectedPeers
            } catch let error as NSError {//Shows an error message if there is a problem
                print(error)
            }



    }
```